# Emacs keeps highlighting the word 'fix' in every context - how do I turn it off?

Tags: font-lock

In pretty much every mode, whenever the word 'fix' occurs, whether its in a comment or not, it gets highlighted in a *very* visible way. I'm not sure what's causing this, and would like to turn it off. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you try `M-x unhighlight-regexp` and choose one from the possibilities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably a font lock customization that one can add to their `init.el`.

I have the following that highlights the occurrences of `FIXME`, `TODO` and `BUG` in `font-lock-warning-face` face. But I have bound this to happen only in a particular major mode hook (i.e. only when a particular major mode is active).

```
 
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\b\\(FIXME\\|TODO\\|BUG\\)\\b" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)))
```

My gut feeling is that you have a similar `(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\b\\(FIX\\|...` statement somewhere in your `init.el`.

I would do a recursive grep of `FIX\\\\` in the emacs setup folder ( which usually is `~/.emacs.d` ) to find the location of that statement.

Comment: And if you do not want such highlighting everywhere, then don't make it global. Just put the `font-lock-add-keywords` sexp on mode hooks for modes where you really want it. Font lock is designed to be mode-specific, in general.

Answer (score 6):

Put point (the cursor) on the word `fix` and do <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd> (`what-cursor-position`). In the buffer that comes up, look for a section that looks like this:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 font-lock-comment-face
  fontified            t
```

Move point to whatever it says instead of `font-lock-comment-face` (you can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate there), and hit <kbd>RET</kbd>. You can also click the name of the face with the mouse.

This will bring up a `*Help*` buffer showing you properties of the face in question. The first line will look something like this:

```
Face: font-lock-comment-face (sample) (customize this face)
```

To modify the face, click `customize this face`. You will probably want to change the "Foreground" and "Background" properties. When you are done, click "Apply and Save" to make the changes permanent.

---

Here is **another way** to find out what's going on:

1. Quit Emacs and start it again via `emacs -Q`. The `-Q` flag tells Emacs to refrain from loading any customizations. If `fix` is not being highlighted any more, this means that the problem is coming from your personal customizations (or from a third-party package you are using).
2. *Recursively bisect* your init-file: Start by commenting out half of it, restart Emacs, and see if `fix` gets highlighted. If it does, you know that the code that's causing the highlighting is in the portion of the code that is currently *not* commented out (and vice versa). Repeat the process for the portion of the code you know contains the offending code: Comment out half of it, and see if the problem persists. Keep going until you have narrowed the problem down to a small chunk of code. Add the offending code to your question if you need more assistance with it.

   To comment out a chunk of code, put it in a region and hit <kbd>M-;</kbd> (bound to `comment-dwim` by default). If a region is already commented out, you can use the same command to uncomment it.

Comment: I tried that - it's coming from something called ``idle-highlight``, and the only thing that's set is ``Inherit: region``. I've tried unsetting that, but it seems to have absolutely no effect.

Comment: @KozRoss Oh -- [this](https://github.com/nonsequitur/idle-highlight-mode) `idle-highlight`?

Comment: The very same - it's part of the ``starter-kit`` which I based my Emacs setup off of. I'd do its stuff by hand, but I've never had issues with it before now.

Comment: OK, that's a minor mode. So the immediate fix would be to turn it off via `M-x` `idle-highlight-mode` `RET`.

Comment: I tried that - still the same annoying highlighting.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did it say "Idle-Highlight mode disabled" in the echo area when you did that? Also, if you are sure that `idle-highlight-mode` is off, do `C-u C-x =` again with point on `fix`. Does it show a different face?

Comment: Yes, it did say that. It has a thing called ``font-lock-warning-face``. I tried turning all of its stuff off (which includes an ``inherit`` and a ``background``), but the text is still highlighted.

Comment: Not sure if turning everything off is the right way to go. Try to set a custom color for foreground and background. Also, I'm starting to suspect that the highlighting of that specific word might be caused by some other customizations... If setting "Foreground" and "Background" to custom values does not have any effect, quit Emacs and restart it via `emacs -Q`. Does `fix` still get highlighted?

Comment: With ``emacs -Q``, ``fix`` no longer gets highlighted.

Comment: @KozRoss OK, that's good news. The next step is to recursively bisect your init-file: Start by commenting out one half of it, restart Emacs, see if `fix` gets highlighted. If it does, you know that the code that's causing the highlighting is in the portion of the code that is currently not commented out (and vice versa). Repeat the process for the portion of the code you know contains the offending code: Comment out half of it, and see if the problem persists. This process allows you to quickly zero in on the code that is causing the problem. Report back with your findings.

Comment: @KozRoss To comment out a chunk of code, put it in a region and hit `M-;` (bound to `comment-dwim` by default). If a region is already commented out, you can use the same command to uncomment it.